# Refactoring C++, "no matching function to call"

Tags: c++, arduino, refactoring, esp8266

I'm working at learning how to effectively Separate my C++ code for a ESP8266 project and I'm running into some issues with pulling out the webserver functions and objects. I'm using the sample code from [this](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap10%20-%20Simple%20Web%20Server.html) tutorial as my base point.

I feel like I'm understanding the basics of how to build a class and header, but when trying to use another class within my class I'm getting errors...but only in some of the functions.

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <CServer.h>

CServer clientServer(80); //create a CServer, which will create a private WebServer object on init.

void setup(void)
{     
  clientServer.startRoutes(); //start routes declared in CServer.cpp
  clientServer.begin(); // start the server
} 

void loop(void){
  clientServer.handleClient();                    // Listen for HTTP requests from clients
}
```

This is my CServer.h:

```
//begin include for class CServer to handle client server functions
#ifndef CSERVER_H
#define CSERVER_H

#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
//Client server functions are handled by this class.
ESP8266WebServer
class CServer
{
private:
  ESP8266WebServer server; //local instance of the webserver object
public:
  CServer(int port);

  void handleClient();
  void handleNotFound();
  void handleRoot();
  void begin();
  void startRoutes();
};

#endif
```

And finally the CServer.cpp

```
#include "CServer.h"

CServer::CServer(int port)
{
  ESP8266WebServer server(port); //create a server with the passed port
}

void CServer::handleClient()
{
  server.handleClient();
};

void CServer::handleRoot()
{
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello world!"); // Send HTTP status 200 (Ok) and send some text to the browser/client
}

void CServer::handleNotFound()
{
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "404: Not found"); // Send HTTP status 404 (Not Found) when there's no handler for the URI in the request
}

void CServer::begin()
{
  server.begin();
}

void CServer::startRoutes()
{
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> no matching function for call to
>   'esp8266webserver::ESP8266WebServerTemplate::on(const char
>   [2], )'

for both the handleRoot, and handleNotFound functions i'm trying to pass to "server.on" and "server.onNotFound" at the very end of the .cpp file.

I'm looking to do this kind of thing with many different libraries and such to build a device, and would really like to know how to effectively clean up my code with this strategy, so understanding the right way is critical.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the constructor of `CServer` creates a variable named `server` in the body, which means it does NOT initialise the class member named `server`.   The fact the two things are named `server` does not magically cause them to be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass a non-static member function to `server.on("/", handleRoot);` which expects a callable of signature `void()` (i.e. a callable that can be called without any arguments and returning `void`).

A non-static member function however is not a function callable without any argument. It takes at least one argument, the implicit `this` pointer to the class instance.

If you want the handler to call `handleRoot` on the current class instance on which `startRoutes` was called, then use a lambda to call the member and capture `this`:

```
server.on("/", [this]{ handleRoot(); });
```

---

As @Peter mentioned in the question comments, you are also not initializing the `server` member properly. Instead you are creating a local instance of `ESP8266WebServer`, also called `server`, but which is local to the constructor and destroyed when the constructor leaves. This instance has no relation to the class member instance, except that they share type and name.

If you want to initialize the `server` member with `port` as argument, you can do that in the *member initializer list* of the constructor:

```
CServer::CServer(int port) : server(port)
{
}
```

Comment: This worked! everything is actually functioning as expected. I'm curious about @peter's comment though. What i was trying to do is upon instantiation of the CServer class, i wanted to create a local instance of ESP8266WebServer. That way i can call the functions related to that (different) class on which is what the "server" object is. Am I misunderstanding this? My concern is your statement "which is destroyed when the constructor leaves"

Comment: @Rockclimber399 `ESP8266WebServer server(port);` in the constructor is a normal variable definition as it would also be in any other function. When the function returns, the variable is destroyed. The *class member* named `server`, which lives as long as the `CServer` class instance as part of it, is declared in `CServer`'s class definition with `ESP8266WebServer server;`, not in the constructor.

Comment: In the constructor you can access it simply by its name `server` (if you don't shadow it with another declaration), as you also do in the other member functions. The initializer of a data member (i.e. the `(port)` part in your misplaced variable definition) must be placed in the member initializer list (the thing after the `:` in the constructor) introduced by the data member's name. If you changed the constructor in the way I showed, then the problem Peter mentioned and that you are concerned about, is resolved.

Comment: I think I get it. To clarify. The way I declared 'ESP8266WebServer server(port);' initially, created a local instance of that class that could be used for some reason during the construction of my CServer object, but is destroyed when my Object Instance is returned by the constructor. Declaring it in the way you mentioned, references the 'server' that I'm intending, referenced in the .h file. Meaning, the latter method will keep the Server instance alive, as long as that CServer instance is alive. Ya? I could create two CServer objects, with two ports, and two ESP...Servers would exist aswell?

Comment: @Rockclimber399 Yes correct. (Except that a constructor doesn't really *return* anything. It constructs an object in a given memory location (given by the value of the implicit `this` pointer))

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: It worked for me for ESP32 ESPAsyncWebServer library!! Thanks a lot!